# Anuglar 8: HTTPRequest Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular8

I have no upgraded to Anuglar 8 and have now a problem with my already working HTTP interceptor. With Angular 7 no problem at all.

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (request.url) {
      if (!request.url.startsWith('/')) {
        request = request.clone({
          url:  baseUrl + request.url
        });
      }
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        ([]: HttpEvent<any>) => {  // <------ failure
          // nothing to do ...
        },
        (error: any) => {
    ....
```

I get the strange error:

```
core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at TapSubscriber.next.handle.pipe.logConsole [as _tapNext] (HTTP.Request.Interceptor.ts:55)
    at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:40)
    at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2066)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
```

I thought its the `tap` function which has problems... I tried several approached for a fix but didn't succeed. Since it worked before I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: you need to import `tap`

Comment: Otherwise the code wouldn't compile :-/ That's an error while execution.

Comment: can you share your code on `https://stackblitz.com`

Comment: @LeO Can you change the code like this and try ? `return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        event => console.log(event))`

Answer (score 0):

Debuggig with the suggested approach of Florian I found that the event returns `{type: 0}` - which I Googled for - with solutions.

The problem is that the conversion is incorrect it should look like:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        (response: HttpEvent<any>) => {  
      ....
```

Thx for the efforts

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You were using `[]` which is an *object array* as a *parameter name*. It was weird the code was working before !